# MATLAB code on cloud and returning data to android device

Tags: android, matlab, cloud

What are possible ways to run MATLAB code in a cloud and return the data (in this case a 3D image output) to an android application through web services?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are many ways. You could build a web interface that interacts with Matlab.

But reading through google I noticed that page

http://de.mathworks.com/mobile/?s_tid=desc_mobile_ML_rp

It seems like Matlab provides pretty much what you are looking for.